# How to not repeat results in prolog language

Tags: prolog

So I have this data base in my prolog program about restaurants that have a name and the people working in it and the meals it serves :

```
restaurant(hardees,[abo_abdo,abo_ahmad,tahseen],[grilled_chicken,jambo_beef,grilled_cheese_sandwich,roast_beef]).

restaurant(subway,[eftikar,tahseen,samer],[potato_salad,chicken_rice,jambo_beef,srevice_dish]).

restaurant(mcDonalds,[amer,zaher,maher],[service_dish,beef_stew,potato_corn,grilled_chicken,roast_beef]).

restaurant(kfc,[mufeed,mazen,izdihar,maher],[mushroom_rice,service_dish,jambo_beef]).
```

and I want to know if there's a meal that's present in more than one restaurant.

I have this instruction (and there should only be one parameter for this instruction) :

```
multi_available(X):- restaurant(Y1,_,Z1),member(X,Z1),
restaurant(Y2,_,Z2),Y1 \= Y2 ,member(X,Z2).
```

and it's presenting these results :

```
multi_available(X).
X = grilled_chicken ;
X = jambo_beef ;
X = jambo_beef ;
X = roast_beef ;
X = jambo_beef ;
X = jambo_beef ;
X = service_dish ;
X = grilled_chicken ;
X = roast_beef ;
X = service_dish ;
X = jambo_beef ;
X = jambo_beef ;
```

How can I have my results without the repetition. 
Thanks alot

Comment: Use `setof/3`..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The traditional way is to use `setof/3` or `findall/3` and `sort/2`.  Both however result in first computing all answers and next you have a list of answers.  You can turn that again to a satisfiable goal using `member/2`.

SWI-Prolog offers `library(solution_sequences)`, which provides operators that are known from SQL, such as `distinct/1,2`, `limit/2`, `offset/2`, etc.  Using that, you simply call

```
?- distinct(multi_available(X)).
```

which ensures that variant solutions are removed, gives the first answer as it becomes available and doesn't switch between answers and lists of them so you can easily create more complex queries.